# A common word for person/company/organization?

Tags: word-choice

As we can say *principal* for user/group/role, is there a common word for person/company/organization?

Comment: I do not understand this question. Maybe it would help if you provide a couple of sentences -- one where you use the word principal for user/group/role, and another where you need a word to represent person/company/organization? Thanks!

Comment: @Jay: it's a database table about suppliers and customers, so, a supplier/customer maybe a person, or a company, or an organization. As we have a single table for user/group/role, I'd also want to use a single table for person/company/organization.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The word you are looking for is *party*.

Comment: Can an "organisation" not being a body corporate can be a party to anything?

Comment: That was going to be my guess as well, and Ray's answer reinforces this. The Marx brothers, my source for legal advice, once had this in a contract: "The party of the first part shall be known in this contract as the party of the first part." How do you like that? That's pretty neat, eh? (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SzfiBMRDc5Y)

Comment: Love the Marx Brothers!

Answer (score 3):

In my databases this is known as a *legal entity* (i.e. anything that can be bound by a contract).  Typically, there are 4 main 'types'; Person, Company, Organization, Government

Answer (score 2):

I am taking a wild guess that you are trying to find an economy related term.

How about (economic) "entity"?

Comment: entit...y....oh drat. ;P there it is. +1

Comment: Entity seems too common, i.e., everything looks like an entity.

Answer (score 1):

In most contexts, *legal person* explicitly includes companies and the like.